# Application publisher of Inno Setup made installer not showing on Windows 7 UAC prompts, but does on Windows 10

Tags: inno-setup, bamboo, uac

I am using Inno Setup to create an application installer. Setup file is creating through bamboo and the publisher name is given through bamboo parameters. Both publisher name and icon is showing when we install on Windows 10. But when we install on Windows 7, publisher cannot be identified. *"Unknown publisher"* is shown under publisher.

This is how I set the publisher:

```
#define MyAppPublisher MyAppPublisher  [Setup] PrivilegesRequired=admin  AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
```

[image: windows 7 setup]

[image: windows 10 setup]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both cases, what is shown on the screenshots is not what comes from the Inno Setup `AppPublisher` directive.

The publisher on the UAC popup comes from the executable's *signature*. So it has nothing to do with Inno Setup.

Either those are different binaries. Or the certificate is not trusted on the machine running Windows 7.

Go to *Digital Signatures* tab in the file *Properties* and check the certificate.